# dplyr min on specific values

Tags: sql, r, dplyr

I'd like to do the equivalent of the following `SQL` query in R with `dplyr`:

```
SELECT 
  user_id,
  min(case when product = 'ProductA' then purchase_date end) AS min_purchase_date_product_A,
  min(case when product = 'ProductB' then purchase_date end) AS min_purchase_date_product_B
FROM fact_purchase
GROUP BY user_id;
```

I think I would need to use the `min()` function in combination with `which()` (see proposal below) but the syntax is wrong and I don't know how to combine these two functions!

```
min_purchase_dates_per_product =
fact_purchase %>%
group_by(user_id) %>%
mutate(
min_purchase_date_product_A = min(which(product == 'ProductA')),
min_purchase_date_product_B = min(which(product == 'ProductB'))
)
```

If there is a way to do it for all existing products instead of listing one by one the products in a mutate statement, I'm happy to know how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is to group by both user and product:

```
min_purchase_dates_per_product <-
  fact_purchase %>%
  group_by(user_id, product) %>%
  summarize(min(x))
```

I put `x` as the variable whose minimum we are trying to find.

You can later join this to the original data frame on user_id, product if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Like @luis-usier suggested you should (also in your sql) group by the user and product:

library(dplyr)

```
productTable <- data.frame(user = sample(1:2, size = 10, replace = T), 
                           product = paste0("p", sample(1:2, size = 10, replace = T)),
                           purchaseDate = sample(seq(as.Date('2016/01/01'), as.Date('2016/07/01'), by="day"), 10))
productTable
productTable %>%
  group_by(user, product) %>%
  summarise(minPurchase = min(purchaseDate))
```

as such your data remains tidy!
If you really need to transform your data into a matrix of variables then you can use `tidyr`:

```
productTable %>%
  group_by(user, product) %>%
  summarise(minPurchase = min(purchaseDate)) %>%
  tidyr::spread(key = "product", value = "minPurchase")
```